# Codeigniter set constants in custom library

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter for a project. I have a custom library in which there are constants in which I will use in my custom functions in the library. How do I declare such constants?

Comment: declare constants in the application/config/constants.php. That's where it has to be.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to use that constants only in your library, you must declare it inside of your class:

```
<?php
class my_class {
    const MY_CONSTANT = 10;
```

And then call it with:

```
self::MY_CONSTANT
```

If you need that your constants are available in the rest of the application, you must declare it in your `application/config/constants.php` file

Answer (score 1):

Access the constant in library as this way. It works.

```
 $this->load->library('library_name');
 echo library_name::MY_CONSTANT;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare constants on `config/constants.php` as follows:

```
class MyConstantsClass {

    public static function get_timezones_list() {
        return array(
            "-12" => "(GMT -12:00) Eniwetok, Kwajalein",
            "-11" => "(GMT -11:00) Midway Island, Samoa",
            "-10" => "(GMT -10:00) Hawaii",
            "-9" => "(GMT -9:00) Alaska",
            "-8" => "(GMT -8:00) Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada)",
            "-7" => "(GMT -7:00) Mountain Time (US &amp; Canada)",
            "-6" => "(GMT -6:00) Central Time (US &amp; Canada), Mexico City",
            "-5" => "(GMT -5:00) Eastern Time (US &amp; Canada), Bogota, Lima",
            "-4" => "(GMT -4:00) Atlantic Time (Canada), Caracas, La Paz",
            "-3.5" => "(GMT -3:30) Newfoundland",
            "-3" => "(GMT -3:00) Brazil, Buenos Aires, Georgetown",
            "-2" => "(GMT -2:00) Mid-Atlantic",
            "-1" => "(GMT -1:00) Azores, Cape Verde Islands",
            "0" => "(GMT) Western Europe Time, London, Lisbon, Casablanca",
            "1" => "(GMT +1:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris",
            "2" => "(GMT +2:00) Kaliningrad, South Africa",
            "3" => "(GMT +3:00) Baghdad, Riyadh, Moscow, St. Petersburg",
            "3.5" => "(GMT +3:30) Tehran",
            "4" => "(GMT +4:00) Abu Dhabi, Muscat, Baku, Tbilisi",
            "4.5" => "(GMT +4:30) Kabul",
            "5" => "(GMT +5:00) Ekaterinburg, Islamabad, Karachi, Tashkent",
            "5.5" => "(GMT +5:30) Bombay, Calcutta, Madras, New Delhi",
            "6" => "(GMT +6:00) Almaty, Dhaka, Colombo",
            "7" => "(GMT +7:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta",
            "8" => "(GMT +8:00) Beijing, Perth, Singapore, Hong Kong",
            "9" => "(GMT +9:00) Tokyo, Seoul, Osaka, Sapporo, Yakutsk",
            "9.5" => "(GMT +9:30) Adelaide, Darwin",
            "10" => "(GMT +10:00) Eastern Australia, Guam, Vladivostok",
            "11" => "(GMT +11:00) Magadan, Solomon Islands, New Caledonia",
            "12" => "(GMT +12:00) Auckland, Wellington, Fiji, Kamchatka"
        );
    }   

    public static function get_codes() {        
        return array();
    }

   // .... and so on....

}
```

Then inside your custom library :

```
class MyLibraryClass {

    private $timezones;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->CI =& get_instance(); //in case you need it
        $this->timezones = MyConstantsClass::get_timezones_list();
    }

    //do whatever you want with your constants
    echo $current_timezone = $this->timezones['-5']; //print (GMT -5:00) Eastern Time (US &amp; Canada), Bogota, Lima

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally Codeigniter constants should be inside `config/constants.php`. Then only we can access all the constants in the entire application.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own constants file and just include it in your library:

config/myconstants.php

In your library,

include(APPPATH. 'config/myconstants.php');